# Categorial Tabs Not Displaying in Nav-Bar Despite Using For Loop - Need Assistance

Tags: python, html, django, web, django-templates

I'm trying to add multiple category tabs to the nav-bar using a for loop, but the result doesn't seem to show anything. I'm not sure where I went wrong.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="{% url 'category:category_list' %}" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                    Danh mục sản phẩm
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        {% for category in category_list %}
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category:category_detail' category.id %}">{{ category.category_name }}</a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

[This is result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3Q4P.png)

Comment: Post your view code too.